# How can I release the previous view controller when I change the root view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When my app start launch,the first view controller is `advertisement view controller`,after several seconds the `advertisement view controller` will jump to `main view controller` and I want to set the `main view controller` to root view controller.

Here is my code in the `advertisement view controller`:

```
- (void)gotoMainVC{
Xhany *mainVC = [[Xhany alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *mainNaviController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
[self presentViewController:mainNaviController animated:NO completion:^{
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:mainNaviController];
}];
}
```

**Which makes me have a headache is:**

after jumping to `main view controller` the `dealloc` method of `advertisement view controller` didn't be invoked.

**To solve the issue:**

I write a code in completion block:

```
[self presentViewController:mainNaviController animated:NO completion:^{
    [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] setRootViewController:mainNaviController];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}];
```

**But** the screen become black and the `dealloc` method didn't be invoked,too.

**The reason I want to release the `advertisement view controller` is I would not come back the view controller at all.I wonder if there any way to release the view controller.**

Hope someone can share an idea.Thanks a lot.

Comment: check that any strong iboutlet caused this. make it weak so dealloc method call in advertisement view controller.

Comment: From where you are showing `advertisement view controller`

Comment: @KKRocks I didn't use any iboutlet and I didn't use any xib or storyboard.

Comment: @vp2698 From Appdelegate.m .There is code:
```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navCon;

- (void)gotoAdsVC{
    ADViewController *adVC = [[ADViewController alloc]init];
    self.navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:adVC];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navCon;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

   if (isShowAd) { //Your Condition if You want to put or directly call prepareAd.
      [self prepareAd];
   }else{
      [self setNavRootViewController];
   }
   return YES;
}
```

For show Ad change your rootViewController.

```
- (void)prepareAd {

    AdvertismentViewController *theAdController = [[AdvertismentViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = theAdController;
    // Timer for Your ad.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 //Your time Interval for ad
                                     target:self
                                  selector:@selector(setNavRootViewController)
                                  userInfo:nil
                                   repeats:NO];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

When ad finished change Your rootViewController.

```
- (void)setNavRootViewController {
     Xhany *mainVC = [[Xhany alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
     UINavigationController *mainNaviController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
     self.window.rootViewController = mainNaviController;
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dummy view controller as RootViewController and assign it to your 
NavigationVC in AppDelegate

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

self.rootNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:[[RootViewController alloc] init]];

self.window.rootViewController = self.rootNavigationController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

In View Did Load of your RootVC,add advertisement VC

advertisement  = [[advertisement alloc]init];

```
advertisement.view.frame = self.view.bounds;

[self.view addSubview: advertisement.view];

[self performSelector:@selector(removeSplashScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
```

Remove your advt after 1s

```
[self.splashViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

self.splashViewController = nil;
```

Push your main vc

```
MainVc *mainVc=[[MainVc alloc]init];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:mainVc animated:NO];
```

Comment: Yeah,you are right,but,is there no way if I use real view controller?

Comment: No, there should be a view controller assigned to navigation controller. If you directly assign advt. VC black screen will displayed while doing the pop operation on VC.